# How to have path based routing for AWS Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-route53, aws-application-load-balancer

I have deployed 2 services in ECS Web and API, Both of the services have their ALB, How can I configure my domain as follows:

- example.com -> Web ALB
- example.com/api -> API ALB

I tried creating a single ALB for both web and api target group and added a path based routing in rules but /api request is received by nodejs with full path, Eg. if a call example.com/api/products node is getting /api/products instead of /products

What could be a proper way of implementing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps related: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-application-load-balancer-cli.html#path-based-routing-aws-cli

Answer (score 1):

> call example.com/api/products node is getting /api/products instead of /products

That's correct and **that's how it should work**. In other words, ALB can't change path from `/api/products` to `/products`, because ALB only forwards requests, it does not re-write them.

You can have a look at CloudFront, which could be helpful in that case.